# How can I redirect old WordPress URL (with a query string) to new URL using .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, url

I transferred my WordPress site to static HTML website, but some other website have a link to my old WordPress site `mysite.com/?page_id=1103`.

I want to redirect all traffic to new URL which is `mysite.com/mypage.html`, but my redirect in *.htaccess* file doesn't work. Maybe someone can help me with the line of code in *.htaccess* file. I tried following but it didn't work:

```
Redirect 301 /?page_id=1103 http://mysite.com/mypage.html
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is [an article that answers your question](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/):

> Unfortunately, neither Redirect nor RedirectMatch allow you to specify a query string for the redirect source. It other words, the following statements are invalid and they will simply be ignored.

```
Redirect /page.php?id=3  http://mydomain.site/page/3
Redirect /page.php?id=4  http://mydomain.site/page/4

RedirectMatch ^/page.php?id=([0-9]*)$  http://mydomain.site/page/$1
```

> The solution requires to change the focus from mod_alias to mod_rewrite. Here’s an example.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/page\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.site/page/%1.pdf [R=302,L]
```

So in your case the code should be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=1103$
RewriteRule .* http://mydomain.site/mypage.html [R=301,L]
```